# How to parse datetime.date object into a float

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, matplotlib

I have a program that graphs points that are stored in a postgresql table. The x-coordinate is the date when the query is made and is of the `datetime.date` type. When I try to convert the date to a float to enable it to be graphed, I'm getting the error that the `datetime.date object is not iterable`. Below is the snippet of code that I use in order to parse the data returned from a query:

```
for row in rows:
    pair = (row[0], row[1])
    coordinateList.append(pair)
xs = [dateToNum.datestr2num(x[0]) for x in coordinateList]
ys = [x[1] for x in coordinateList]
```

In the fourth line where the x coordinate is being parsed, I use the datestr2num function from the matplotlib.dates library which is where the problem occurs. With this being the case, what is the proper way to parse the date?

Comment: Can you provide sample data from coordinateList?

Comment: You don't need to parse it, it's already an object. Exactly what kind of value are you trying to get? What should the float signify?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Its not that I'm trying to parse it myself, I'm using `dateToNum.datestr2num(x[0])` to do it because the plot function only takes floats. I was getting the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-08-31`

Comment: @YOBA Currently I only had one row in the table for testing purposes. The x-coordinate is '2015-08-31'

Comment: But there's no need to do that, because it is not a str, so there's no point in using that function. Again, you need to explain what "float" you want, and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you get the data from the postgres table? If you are using for example psycopg2 then you will get a datetime.date in you row-data and you are all set to go using that.

I'm thinking you could use matplotlib and plot your data directly:

```
# Import pyplot and dates from matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
# Set date format and major locator of x-axis
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y%m%d'))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
# Actually plot the data
plt.plot([x[0] for x in rows],[y[1] for y in rows])
# Fix ticklabels so they don't overlap in the figure
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: Actually, this seems to work the best. For some reason though, the date is only displaying the month and the year but not the day. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Sorry but no I don't. The Python strftime defined at [strftime](http://strftime.org/) shows how the formatter works and as you can see the '%d' part means zero-padded day of month.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
In [56]: from datetime import datetime
In [57]: now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%d%m%H%M%S')
In [58]: now
Out[58]: '20153108192131'
In [59]: f = float(now)
In [60]: f
Out[60]: 20153108192131.0
In [61]: type(f)
Out[61]: float
```

The same thing can be done with datetime.date objects:

```
In [62]: type(datetime.now().date())
Out[62]: datetime.date
In [63]: f2 = float(datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y%d%m'))
In [64]: f2
Out[64]: 20153108.0
In [65]: type(f2)
Out[65]: float
```

For plotting dates with matplotlib see examples at [date_demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) and [fixing-common-date-annoyances](http://matplotlib.org/users/recipes.html#fixing-common-date-annoyances) and the [dates](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates) and [ticker](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#module-matplotlib.ticker) modules will be useful.

Comment: Thanks, that does help, idk why someone downvoted the post... The only problem is that now when the point is graphed, the x-axis tick label is displayed as a decimal. I tried leaving it as the datetime type but that returned an error. Do you know of any way to display the x-tick label as a date?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: I added links to two date plotting examples and to the dates and ticker modules at the end of my answer. That way you can click on them which isn't possible in a comment. Also pandas has the capability of querying databases and loading the data directly into a DataFrame (a 2D table structure much like an R data.frame), compatibilty with datetime objects in DataFrame cells and plotting directly from a DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they helped to clear up some confusion